# Why dash is too dark?

Tags: 11.04

I can't get to view the running apps behind the dash...

Comment: Could you extend your question with a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

You're not meant to be able to see apps running behind the dash. It is slightly transparent (for aesthetic reasons) but you need to close it to get back to your programs.